# how to set color before validate the field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one password field in which there is validations example

```
Password must have:
6-14 characters
1 Lower case character (a-z)
1 Numeric character (0-9)
1 special character (Such as #, $, %, &, !)
```

I used regex to validate my field it also works.But I want if any validation fulfilled then it becomes `green` Example if user type `a` then `1 Lower case character (0-z)` is green other becomes `red`.

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/wimeyurolu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
$(function(){
  $('#password').on('keyup',function(){
    var $this =$(this),
        val=$this.val();
  var reg =/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{6,14}/
    console.log(reg.test(val))

  })
})


.red {
  color:red;
}

.green {
  color:green;
}
.grey-dot {
    background: #808080;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.green-dot {
    background: #77bc3f;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.red-dot {
    background: #fff;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff4848;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to create separate regular expressions to check each separate criteria has been met for the dots to be highlighted. Also, I find it really frustrating when an maximum length is imposed on a password. Why do that? It *should be* stored as a hash anyway, so the length shouldn't make a difference to the application.

Comment: ok i will try and update you